# Friend passed me this note after lecture

Tags: cipher, enigmatic-puzzle

After my linear algebra lecture ended at 3:30 today, my friend passed me this note, but it seems to be encrypted in some way that I don't understand. What question is my friend asking, and what is the answer?

[image: jjj]

Feedback is appreciated, and I will add hints if necessary.

Hint 1:

> There is a very good reason the characters look the way they do. It's not a simple substitution cipher.

Hint 2:

> What does The class I'm Taking have To do with The cipher?

Comment: Seems like a sub cipher...

Comment: is it in english?

Comment: @ColourDalnet Yes, the cipher is in English.

Comment: if it is a substitution cipher, it looks like spaces may be substituted as well. there is a space at the end of the third line, implying that maybe the original string is literally each line placed end to end with no spaces in between, but that would leave a very long word at the end of line one beginning of line two. so, I think the space may be a cipher as well, and the actual spaces are encoded

Comment: Does linear algebra have anything to do with the answer?

Comment: @GrantGarrison That is a good question.

Comment: im sure another good question would be about the significance of ending at 3:30

Comment: @tom I forget, was it 3:30 or 6:15? I always get the hour and minute hands mixed up :)

Comment: Are these characters somehow connected to the korean alphabet? Some of them look exactly like their syllables and consonants.

Comment: Thinking about other languages is the wrong way to go.

Comment: All of the Ts in the second hint are capitolized.  I am thinking we need to transpose the message.

Comment: Very nice puzzle, and great hints (especially those in the comments). They tread that fine line of being good enough to give a nudge in the right direction without making things too easy.

Comment: @Phylyp Thank you. This is my first cipher, so I didn't know exactly how it would go over. I like to do something more creative than some random combination of well-known ciphers (substitution, caesar, etc). Now, what should my next puzzle be...

Answer (score 27, accepted):

First of all, great puzzle! I am currently in Linear Algebra myself.

> As is hinted with the capitalization of 'T' in hint 2, we first take the transpose of the whole message
>  [image]
>  
>  Then rewrite the message with the rows side by side.
>  [image]
>
>  This gives the outlines of block letters, which reads as: `WHAT MATRIX OPERATION DID WE LEARN TODAY?`
>
>  The answer to this is, of course, matrix transposition.

Comment: Hey, you got it! Just so you know, there was also a subtle hint in 3:30 vs 6:15 in the comments. In those times, the hour hand and minute hand swap horizontal/vertical positions.

Comment: @tyobrien - I've edited your answer to make it clearer what Riley's friend was asking, since it took me a few attempts to see it.

Comment: This is super clever!

Comment: Man, I cant even understand it reading this answer. LOL

Answer (score 1):

Partial Answer:

> The references to linear algebra and the capital Ts in the hint suggest that a transpose operation may be in order to read the message.  I took the original image and transposed it as you would when taking the transpose of a matrix.  The fact the letters are aligned to still make rows makes me think this may be the right track.
>  [image: transposed image]

After getting this, with the new message I:

> tried placing a unique letter to represent each symbol to use in a substitution cypher:
>
>     abaz
>     acde
>      aba
>     cdee
>     ywx 
>     afag
>     hecd
>     eafa
>     ia j
>     aja 
>     abah
>      akh
>     caei
>     a de
>     fjac
>     la ?
>
>   Unfortunately, I didn't get anywhere with this.

Comment: Hmm, you might be onto something. :) But keep Hint 1 in mind. And one hint: The transpose of $\begin{bmatrix}8&8\\8&8\end{bmatrix}$ is not $\begin{bmatrix}\infty&\infty\\\infty&\infty\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: Brilliant comment, @Riley :-)