# Hidden in plain sight

Tags: cipher, enigmatic-puzzle

My good friend Joseph Schmo, who I probably just made up, handed me this mysterious note. And right after I figured out [what my other fictitious friend's note said](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/62550/friend-passed-me-this-note-after-lecture)! What is Joseph's favorite pastime?

[image]

Hint:

> Joseph's favorite number is 7

Comment: This riddle is...inspiring

Comment: @Jordan.J.D Thank you, what about it is inspiring?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Joseph probably likes

> Creating and solving puzzles on https://puzzling.stackexchange.com!
>
>  If we namely group the symbols into groups of 7 and put the different groups (without the circles) below each other in a grid, we get the following:
>  [image]

Comment: That is indeed what Joseph's all about. Good job!

Comment: I actual have that symbol drawn a graph paper since Thursday, but i could not figure out how it related to activity, because I thought the question was "What is Joseph's favorite pastime?"

Comment: I just realized what it is, it the sites logo, can't believe i missed that

Answer (score 0):

Probably not it, but just for fun:

> Downhill skiing, performing the odd trick and dodging snowballs, this is just the note he scribbled on the way down keeping track of what happened.

PS, for the hint:

> He makes sure his run always finishes when the total amount of scribbles is a multiple of 7, he really does love that number :)

Comment: Sorry, but your answer takes some interpretive leaps as big as the ones you take while downhill skiing. This also doesn't explain the title.

Comment: Hehe, well it's the first thing that came to my mind when I saw the note which could read like "snowball, snowball, left, jump right..." and so on, I see a few possible flips and crashes in there.. hidden in plain sight means it's easy to overlook right? Which you easily would looking at this with a 100% crypto mindset, so i went with the enigmatic tag.. :)

Comment: If you randomly rearranged the characters in the note, it would no longer make sense. The correct answer should account for the order of the characters within the message, not just the way the individual characters look.