# Not another one! ²

Tags: riddle, cipher, enigmatic-puzzle

That's right, I have received yet another [note](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/62829/hidden-in-plain-sight)! Who passed it to me this time?

[image]

Comment: I'm likely wrong, but it kind of looks reminds me of a pig-pen cipher, but where you over laid multiple symbols on top of each other.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think to the answer to the riddle (which I found just to late, but credits to xhienne) is:

> Automaton
>  My prefix goes vroom: auto
>  My infix you consume: tomato
>  My suffix break shelf: As Misha Lavrov noticed, this might mean that putting "a ton" of stuff on a shelf breaks the shelf.
>  I operate all by myself: by definition

Bonus picture of the riddle:

> [image]

Comment: Hey, you got it! Sorry about the confusing third line. See my comment on xhienne's answer. Do you think you can explain that line now?

Comment: @Riley I read your comment but don't understand the third line

Comment: I think the idea with the third line is that (rot13) vs lbh chg "n gba" bs fghss ba n furys, vg jvyy "oernx furys".

Answer (score 17):

Partial answer: the following riddle appears...

> ... if you draw the lines that are missing in the patterns:
>
> My prefix goes vroom
> My infix you consume
> My suffix breaks helf <sup>(1)</sup>
> I operate all by myself
>
> <sup>(1)</sup> Should actually be read "break(s) shelf"

Not my level unfortunately, so I leave this typical Riley riddle to true amateurs.

Comment: Nice! The third line should actually be rot13(Zl fhssvk oernx furys). I hope you'll excuse the bad grammar, I just wanted to make the lines around the same length.

Comment: Being myself a non-English speaker, you are obviously pardoned for that bad grammar of yours :-) Updating my answer then